# How to update table with multiple if statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using a form to send up to 10 ItemID's to a PHP file. A side from the ItemID's I'm sending a "Status update" to let the user change the status of all those ID's. In this way I've managed to create an Admin function for my clients.

ItemID's are the primary trigger for most things and contains some information about the instrument such as Name, Description, location, etc.. ItemID's are simply unique for ONE instrument.

One part of every ItemID is the GroupID. The GroupID assemble what group an instrument belongs to. If an instrument contains of multiple parts it will be forced in to a group.

**1.** Let's say we've got this instrument bellow, a temperature sensor (ID: 1437) which contains of 2 sensors (ID: 1438, 1439) and the big calculator in it's highest majestic form. This instrument and the "extra" parts will be added to groupid = "10".

**2.** So with my code I want to scan every itemID for a groupID. If the groupID is over 0 change all the itemID's (under the specific group) to the status which been sent from the form. In the same time I want the function to change the status of all itemID's entered (mostly items where groupID="0"). In this way the user doesn't have to scan every part of a group and saves a lot of time for other work during the day.

**3.** The problem with the function in this state is that it will only change the status of either ONE group or ONLY the itemID's entered to the form. I need some advice to get me rolling with this function.

**1.**

[image: 1]

**2.**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") OR die(' Could not connect');
$db = mysql_select_db('book1', $con);
$CalDate= $_POST["CalDate"];
$DueDate= $_POST["DueDate"];
$itemID1= $_POST["itemID1"];
...
$itemID10= $_POST["itemID10"];
$groupidset= $_POST["groupid"];
$status= $_POST["status"];
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){
    $DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
    $result = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1','$itemID2','$itemID3','$itemID4','$itemID5','$itemID6','$itemID7','$itemID8','$itemID9','$itemID10','$groupidset')");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT groupid FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1','$itemID2','$itemID3','$itemID4','$itemID5','$itemID6','$itemID7','$itemID8','$itemID9','$itemID10','$groupidset')");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        $groupid = $row["groupid"];
    }
    if(($groupid == 0)){
        $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status/ADM', verification='No'";
        if($CalDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",CalDate='$CalDate'";
        }
        if($DueDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";
        }
        $upd.=" WHERE itemID IN ('$itemID1', '$itemID2', '$itemID3', '$itemID4', '$itemID5', '$itemID6', '$itemID7', '$itemID8','$itemID9', '$itemID10')";
    }
    if(!empty($groupid)){   
        $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status/ADM', verification='No' WHERE groupid IN ('$groupid')";
        if($CalDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",CalDate='$CalDate'";
        }
        if($DueDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this! Either way the ItemID can only take two routes in the first lines and the rest is self explained. I know it's a messy code but it works as i should!

```
if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){
    $DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
    $result1 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID1')");
    ....
    $result10 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID IN('$itemID10')");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
        $groupid1 = $row["groupid"];
        echo 'ItemID1, Groupid1: ';
        echo $groupid1;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    .....
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result10)){
        $groupid10 = $row["groupid"];
        echo 'ItemID10, Groupid10: ';
        echo $groupid10;
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    if(isset($itemID1) && isset($itemID2) && isset($itemID3) && isset($itemID4) && isset($itemID5) && isset($itemID6) && isset($itemID7) && isset($itemID8) && isset($itemID9) && isset($itemID10)){    
        $upd = "UPDATE booking SET status='$status/ADM', verification='No'";
        if($CalDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",CalDate='$CalDate'";
        }
        if($DueDate !=''){
            $upd.= ",DueDate='$DueDate'";
        }
        $upd.= " WHERE ";
        if($groupid1 != 0){
            $upd.= "groupid IN('$groupid1')";
            if($groupid2 != 0){
                $upd.=" OR groupid IN('$groupid2')";
            }
            ....
            if($groupid10 != 0){
                $upd.=" OR groupid IN('$groupid10')";
            }
            if($groupid10 == 0){
                $upd.=" OR itemid IN('$itemID10')";
            }
        }
        if(empty($groupid1)){
            $upd.= "itemid IN('$itemID1')";
            if($groupid2 != 0){
                $upd.=" OR groupid IN('$groupid2')";
            }
            if($groupid2 == 0){
                $upd.=" OR itemid IN('$itemID2')";
            }
            ....
            if($groupid10 != 0){
                $upd.=" OR groupid IN('$groupid10')";
            }
            if($groupid10 == 0){
                $upd.=" OR itemid IN('$itemID10')";
            }
        }
    }
```